# Ruby - Evaluation within string

Tags: ruby

I have a loop, and in it want to assign a string to the value of i + (i-1) but am not sure how to progress.

```
(1..50).each do |i|
   answer = "#{i+(i-1)}"
end
```

In this code the answer must be a string as it will eventually relate to a database table.

What is the best way of evaluating this within the string, I have tried a few variations of this but haven't had any luck so any helpful pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What result you want to see?

Comment: I want the answer in a format such that, if i = 20, the answer gives 39 etc

Comment: It might be useful to us to explain why you want to do this. Generally sticking code into a string and evaluating it isn't recommended, and there are ways in Ruby to dynamically generate code not using `eval`. Right now this sounds like an XY Problem and you're asking about Y instead of X.

Comment: Currently it just gives, 20+19

Comment: Your code is fine. There's just not much point to it. When `i=1`, `result` is assigned to the string `"1"`. When `i=2`, `result` is reassigned to `"3"`, and so on. The loop returns the last value of `result`, which is `"99"`. Perhaps you want `Array.new(50) { |i| "#{2*i+1}" } #=> ["1", "3",..., "99"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
(1..50).map{|i| i + (i-1)}.map(&:to_s)
```

`Map` will take `Rage` and perform addition written in block on each element and then return transformed `Array`(`Array` and `Range` are enumerable types) which we pass once more to `map` and `&:to_s` is ruby's syntactic sugar that turns `to_s` into a block that can be passed to map. It is equal to `.map {|i| i.to_s}`

Comment: Please don't use `sth`. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum, it's more like an online reference book. We value correct grammar and clarity. Also, please explain why the code is the solution to the problem. Simply handing out code only solves this problem. Explaining why to use it helps in the future when a similar problem occurs too.